# How to find rotation Angle, so two point's Y-axis is same

Tags: python, math

I have two points like this

[image]

I want to rotate the image, so it looks like this:

[image]

I have the code to rotate the image. I just want to find the rotation angle like 5 degrees, 2 degrees.

I have the coordinates of both the points like `50,100` and `150, 94` (X,Y). I want to rotate the image such that, both Y-axis points become 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find rotation angle using `math.atan2` function with point coordinates.

```
angle = math.atan2(p2.y-p1.y, p2.x-p1,x)
```

---

Note that rotation about coordinate origin would shift the first point also, so you perhaps need to make rotation about the first point.